# Ansible command module concatenate variable and string?

Tags: yaml, ansible

Is it possible to do something like this with Ansible's command module?

```
- command: {{ venv_path }}/bin/python {{ repo_path }}/manage.py runserver
```

Since there are no double quotes around the first set of braces, I get the usual "We could be wrong..." syntax error.  But none of the following work either:

```
- command "{{ venv_path }}"/bin/python ... # Error
- command "{{ venv_path }}/bin/python" ... # Error
- command: "{{ venv_path }}/bin/python {{ repo_path }}/manage.py runserver" # Error
```

Thanks.

Comment: Does the last one really result into the same error as the other examples? This last line looks like it should work - or at least not fail due to the *"We could be wrong..."* syntax error.

Comment: yep, @udondan, I just created an example and cannot reproduce it. Robert, please give a sample example that fails, using something like "ls" as the command.

Comment: You can also try `- command: >` and then put the rest on the next line. Then it is treated as text in YAML and it wont complain

Comment: @Jim Upvote and accept my answer if you think it is useful so that others know this is the right answer, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

try `shell: "{{ venv_path }}/bin/python {{ repo_path }}/manage.py runserver"`